# Maximum Value of a Variable that follows Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

I've been trying to solve the following problem for days, but I haven't found anything similar to that on the internet:

So, we have a random variable $X$ that follows the Normal distribution with mean $\mu=60$ and standard deviation $\sigma=4$. Also, we have a density function $f(X) = Y = a_1X + a_0$, which in this case represents a cost, so $\min f(X) = 0$. We are looking for the mean $\Bbb E[f(X)]$.

We know that $$\Bbb E[f(X)] = \int_{\min f(X)}^{\max f(X)} xf(x)\,dx.$$ The problem is we don't know the maximum value that $f$ can take. However, we know that the variable $X$ follows the Normal distribution. Would it be correct to assume that the maximum value of $X$ is $\mu+3\sigma$?

If that's the case, then could we also assume that $$\max f(X) = a_1\max X + a_0 = a_1(\mu+3\sigma) + a_0 = 72a_1 + a_0?$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your $f(X)$ is  not a density.  It is instead a function of a random variable, so a random variable itself.  As far as I can tell $f(x)= \max(0,a_1x+a_0)$ so here $f(X)$ has a censored normal distribution with no limit on the upside, so talking about its maximum is probably inappropriate.  You can still find $E[f(X)]$, and if in this case  $a_1$ and $a_0$ are both positive then  it will be $60 a_1+a_0$ plus a tiny amount you can lose in the rounding

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why E( f(X) ) = 60a1 + a0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $\Bbb E[f(X)]=\Bbb E[a_1X+a_0]=a_1\Bbb E[X]+a_0=60a_1+a_0$ due to linearity of $\Bbb E$, and also that $f$ has no minimum or maximum as neither does $X$.

Comment: I forgot about the linearity of E. Thank you very much!! Does the same thing applies to the Standard deviation of f(x)?

Comment: Similar, but not the same. We have $\Bbb V[f(X)]=\Bbb V[a_1X+a_0]=a_1^2\Bbb V[X]\implies\operatorname{SD}[f(X)]=a_1\operatorname{SD}[X]$; in particular, the constant $a_0$ disappears as it has no variance.